# What is the limit of $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+y^2}{y}?$

Tags: limits, polar-coordinates

I am somewhat rusty with the limits when changing polar coordinates and the following question has arisen.

What is the limit of $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+y^2}{y}?$$

In Wolfram, $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+y^2}{y}=0$ but, in polar coordinates, with $\theta=r$
$$\lim_{r\to 0, \theta=r} \frac{r}{\sin(\theta)}=\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{r}{\sin(r)}=1$$.

The limit not exists? Thanks.

Comment: $x=r\cos \theta$ not $r\sin \theta$

Comment: sorry I put x wrong and it was y. I fixed it.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2715439/505767

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach the limit along two different paths; $y=x$ and $y=x^2.$ Can you complete now? Even in polar version also the limit value varies with the different values of $\theta!$

Comment: Thanks. I have just understood. Yes, I was confused by the fact that in general $r\cos(\theta)\to 0$ if $r\to 0$, but that's true since $\cos(\theta)$ is bounded (just because of that)

Comment: Welcome. That's great.